# How can I make this touchable?

Tags: android, libgdx

I can only move my player from my keyboard, but I want it to work for both mobile touch and keyboard. 
This is how it looks and works for keyboard.

```
 if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ANY_KEY)) {
        if (!keyPressed) {
            keyPressed = true;
            if (player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 4) {
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.3f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);

            }
            Hud3.addscore(1);
        }
    } else {
        keyPressed = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
```

and Override certain functions like

**boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)

public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)

 public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer)**

Full tutorial available at this link:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx

Comment: Also, you can use the InputListener and override keyDown() instead of Gdx.input.isKeyPressed() on every frame